# As close to flat as possible

Tags: code-challenge, restricted-source, random, open-ended-function, busy-beaver

Write a program or function that fulfills the following

- Scores less than 101 bytes under normal [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) rules
- Takes no input<sup>1</sup> and always outputs a single integer.
- Every integer is a possible output.

Your score will be the probability of the most frequent integer occurring, with a lower scoring being the goal.  That is \$\mathrm{sup}\left\{P(x)|x\in\mathbb{Z}\right\}\$.

Since a few of these properties are not program decidable, you should be ready to provide a proof that your answer is valid and obtains the score it claims.

---

<sup>1</sup> You may optionally take a stream of random bits, or a subroutine which produces random bits on each call as an input to provide randomness.  Each bit will be uniform and independent of other bits.

Answer (score 10):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), score \$\approx \frac{1}{\sqrt{8\pi\lambda}}\$ where \$\lambda \approx 9\uparrow\uparrow (9\uparrow \uparrow (9 \uparrow \uparrow (9 \uparrow \uparrow (9\uparrow\uparrow 9)))))\$

[This is `g(9)`](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=9%5E9%5E9%5E9%5E9%5E9%5E9%5E9%5E9%5E0), approximately `10^(10^(10^(10^(10^(10^(10^8.567841344463464))))))`; I'm doing `g(g(g(g(g(9)))))` to get the \$\lambda\$ above.

\$a \uparrow b\$ ([Knuth's up-arrow notation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%27s_up-arrow_notation)) is `a` to the power of `b`. \$a \uparrow\uparrow b\$ is `a` to the power of itself, `b` times. So \$9\uparrow\uparrow 3 = 9^{9^9}\$ and \$9\uparrow\uparrow 9 = 9^{9^{9^{9^{9^{9^{9^{9^{9}}}}}}}}\$

```python
from numpy.random import*
g=lambda n:n and 9**g(n-1)
print(choice([-1,1])*poisson(g(g(g(g(g(9)))))))
```

[DON'T Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Tck9CoAwDEDh3VN0TIoKxUnBk4hD/asFm4Rah56@Ovq2jyc5nUxdKUfkoOgJkttoafvgg3BMunLjZcOyWUUDqW@pXmsH1BisJHpKsJ7s1x2mxtRmRi3s75sJHPT/ELGUFw) Blows the recursion limit, of course.

How it works:

The [Poisson distribution](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution) is a random distribution that, by itself, already generates random positive integers from 0 to infinity. This distribution takes a parameter, \$\lambda \$, that affects how likely the smaller integers are. What we have to do is set \$\lambda\$ in such a way that small numbers become **very** unlikely.

Then we use [the wiki page](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution) again to realize the *mode* of the distribution is related to its parameter and then we plug the mode into the probability density function to get the program's score. After that we use Sterling's approximation to simplify the expression to something that is only slightly more digestible.

If I really can't waive the recursion limit then a similar approach with a loop gives

#### [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), score \$\approx \frac{1}{\sqrt{8\pi\lambda}}\$ where \$\lambda = 9\uparrow\uparrow (9 \uparrow\uparrow 7)\$

```python
from numpy.random import*
print(choice([-1,1])*poisson(eval('**'.join(`9`*9**9**9**9**9**9**9**9))))
```

[Don't try it online!](https://tio.run/##bYwxCoAwDEV3T@FmDCro5llEUNTSiE1CrYKnrwVXP294b/n6BCvcxWi8uJwvp0/jZ15TkFPxATP1xAEWK7RsMNRt1Y4lqtB5CsN2zwcUiEWzCzFM/YQ9/lGmxe/KQJf8BQ) Got some more bigness because @xnor taught me how `join` works when used directly on strings.

Comment: You could add another `9` as your code-golf score is only 99.

Comment: Why would this still crash given unlimited RAM and time?

Comment: Because python defaults to a recursion limit of 1000 and you have to set the recursion limit to be higher in the program if you want it to be @RGS

Comment: Because Python imposes a hard limit on recursion depth, regardless of RAM. You can override it with sys.setrecursionlimit.

Comment: @Grimmy I believe we may assume recursion limits can be set arbitrarily high unless otherwise dictated. I see nothing concrete on meta at a quick glance.

Comment: @JonathanAllan ah if that is true, then I may revert my edit... Who is "right", then? Because this new version is definitely not as impressive

Comment: I've written plenty of answers in Python that hit the default recursion limit. Usually this is once input gets large enough. Here we take no input, but answers to this question cannot complete in reality as we know it anyway, so I can't see what's extra special about a recursion limit, over say time or space. If people feel there needs to be clarification then head to meta. I'm using recursion in my Jelly answer too and Jelly does `sys.setrecursionlimit(1 << 30)` so it would come under the same ruling; I don't feel one should write an interpreter in another language just to avoid this.

Comment: ...actually looping gained me a byte to use in the end.

Comment: @JonathanAllan thanks for your PoV. At this point, my iterative solution is almost as competitive as the recursive one, but the recursive still has more 9s

Comment: Nvm, just abused recursion again

Comment: My experience has been that's its standard in Python golfing here to ignore the recursion limit as a machine limit like memory.

Comment: @xnor thanks for your sharing your experience here, in particular because it helps me out :D do you have any idea how we could compare the couple of answers that we have right now?

Comment: I'll leave it to the Gooolologists to compare them :) It looks like your iterative solution can squeeze out some more bigness by just joining a string directly `'**'.join("9"*stuff)`, which should give you some room to make the `stuff` bigger, maybe enough to beat your recursive solution.

Comment: Looking at the [numpy random library](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/routines.random.html), there's options similar to Poisson that would save you from having to generate the sign yourself. Like, I think `normal()*BIG` has the right property except it gives non-integers, which can be fixed with `normal()*BIG//1`. And `randn` is same as `normal` but shorter. An ideal thing would be like Poisson but including negatives. There might be something like that in the list.

Comment: @xnor had no idea `join` worked like that on strings, made the `stuff` bigger already. But this still doesn't beat the recursive solution, the power tower isn't big enough. As to the sign generation, I'll have a look ASAP.

Answer (score 9):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), score 0.5 / 1000!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

*bug fix thanks to FryAmTheEggman*

*+1 `!` thanks to ExpiredData*

```
 [₄!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!LΩ#¼]¾D±)Ω
```

[(dont't) Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f8/@lFTiyKNgM@5lcqH9sQe2udyaKPmuZX//wMA) (will timeout).

[Try it online without the factorials](https://tio.run/##AR0A4v9vc2FiaWX//1vigoRMzqkjwrxdwr5EwrEpzqn//w)

```
[           ]            # loop:
 ₄                       #  1000
  !!...!                 #  take the factorial, 88 times
        LΩ               #  pick a random number from 1 to that many
          #              #  if the number was 1, exit the loop
           ¼             #  increment counter_variable
             ¾           # after the loop: push counter_variable
              D±         # push its bitwise negation
                )        # wrap the two in a list
                 Ω       # pick a random element of that list
```

Any integer would work instead of `1000!!...!`, so this approach could score as low as `0.5 / BB(89)`, where `BB` is 05AB1E's Busy Beaver function.

Comment: Sorry, from your explanation I failed to understand how your program can generate arbitrarily large numbers.

Comment: @RGS Think "number of consecutive heads until you get tails". This can be 0, but it can also be arbitrarily large if you get a lot of heads in a row. This is the same, but instead of flipping a 2-sided coin, we flip a 1000!!!... sided dice (and only stop on 1, so that 0, the most likely number, has probability 1/1000!!!...).

Comment: @ExpiredData indeed, that saves one byte.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman that's a bug in legacy 05AB1E, i switched to modern 05AB1E to work around it.

Comment: @Grimmy starting to think a construction like `∞₄ùJ` will grow faster but I'm not sure.. or even just `₄LJLJLJLJLJLJ...`

Comment: @ExpiredData [₄LJ is barely bigger than ₄!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//UVOLj5ctF5BStP3/HwA), so it's definitely way smaller than `₄!!` (which is the fair comparison, since `LJ` takes up two bytes). `ùJ` is better than LJ, but still not nearly as good as `!!`.

Comment: @Grimmy is it enough to say that g^2(x) > f(x) for some x therefore g^n(x) is always greater than f^(n/2)(x)

Comment: One additional `!` by using `1µ₄LΩ}N` instead of `[₄LΩ#¼]¾`

Comment: what would happen if you'll try to index that into `λ₁₁m}`?

Comment: or `λžJ₁mLJ}`, and it also might be possible to duplicate/triplicate it and then index the output to it again

Comment: something like `λžJ₁m}©₄èƒ®sè}ƒ®sè}ƒ®sè}ƒ®sè}ƒ®sè}ƒ®sè}ƒ®sè}ƒ®sè}ƒ®sè}ƒ®sè}ƒ®sè}ƒ®sè}ƒ®sè}ƒ®sè}ƒ®sè}ƒ®sè}`

Comment: in fact you can probably put them inside eachother like `λžJ₁m}©₄èƒ®sèƒ®sèƒ®sèƒ®sèƒ®sèƒ®sèƒ®sèƒ®sèƒ®sèƒ®sèƒ®sèƒ®sèƒ®sèƒ®sèƒ®sèƒ®sè}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}`

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 1 / 2M ?*,

* Any help scoring this appreciated, 0 and -1 are the two equally most likely answers at \$\frac{1}{2M}\$ - see code breakdown.

Inspiration taken from [Grimmy's 05AB1E answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200809/53748).

```
‘ɼµ⁹!!!!;”!ẋ$VƊ;”!ẋ$VƊ;”!ẋ$VƊ;”!ẋ$VƊ;”!ẋ$VƊ;”!ẋ$VƊ;”!ẋ$VƊ;”!ẋ$VƊ;”!ẋ$VƊ;”!ẋ$VƊ;”!ẋ$VƊ;”!ẋ$VƊX’µ¿~2X¤¡
```

[No point trying this online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9Rw4yTew5tfdS4UxEIrB81zFV8uKtbJexY12BgRzxqmHlo66H9dUYRh5YcWvj/PwA)

**[Try incrementing with 4 increment tetrations](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9Rw4yTew5tNQLScGT9qGEukHq4q1sl7FgX8byIRw0zD209tL/OKOLQkkML//8HAA)** (with incrementing the self-referential tetration is just doubling, also start with 2 rather than 256 so n=(2+1+1+1+1)*2*2*2*2=96, much more likely to terminate)

#### How?

```
‘ɼµ⁹!!!!;”!ẋ$VƊ;”!ẋ$VƊ ... X’µ¿~2X¤¡ - Link, no arguments
                              ¿      - while...
  µ                          µ       - ...condition: monadic chain (f(0)):
   ⁹                                 -     256
    !                                -     factorial = 256*255*...*1 = a
     !                               -     factorial = a*(a-1)*...*1 = b
      !                              -     factorial = b*(b-1)*...*1 = c
       !                             -     factorial = c*(c-1)*...*1 = A
              Ɗ                      -     last three links as a monad:
            $                        -       last two links as a monad:
         ”!                          -         literal '!' character
           ẋ                         -         repeated A times
        ;                            -       concatenate to A -> number A with A '!' after it
             V                       -       evaluate as Jelly code -> A!!..! * (A!!..!-1) * ... * 1
               ;”!ẋ$VƊ               -     call that B and repeat that process
                       ...           -     repeat 10 more times giving us M
                           X         -     choose a random integer in [1..M] inclusive
                            ’        -     decrement (i.e. while random choice != 1)
                                   ¡ - repeat...
                                  ¤  - ...number of times:
                                2    -   two
                                 X   -   random integer in [1,2] inclusive
                               ~     - ...action: bitwise NOT
```

Comment: What is M here?

Comment: See the code breakdown - I don't know how to measure it - take \$A=256!!!\$ and apply factorial \$A\$ times to \$A\$ to yield \$B\$, now apply factorial \$B\$ times to \$B\$ to yield \$C\$ ... etc. to yield \$M\$.

Answer (score 3):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 99 bytes

```c
f(b,t)long b(),t;{for(b()/4503599627370496&&printf("-");t-9007199254740992;t=b())putchar(t%10+48);}
```

`b` is a function returning 52 random bits in the form of an integer in the range of [0, 9007199254740992).

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY8xb4MwEIV3/worVZGtQkoSEopIu1QdOnRL10RgG3ISMcg@MjTKb6cGgqqoXnz36b27dyIohei6guU@8qrWJc0Z9zG9FLVhrnyO1uFqnSSbZbyKwyjZeF5jQGPBZsGMpxgkYRgvkmS5juIodH@Kr87GmxbFMTMMHxfhU/TC02v3AFpUrVR022qwKOfHN/LHHKgg/8egvkcIJ9UTMmQ1mZY5IOPkQqh7RmFr9IAZp3vKWC/jt367pQuXhFwJcRfQUwaanWuQk9uiaQXSfoVtlKBo04G32kKplaS9y2XXgJBV8KNkSgbB5DiUCpmH1qe7z6@Pw/fund8UdoiAdo7ng7Zu9p6OzVg7XwNj5Lv5k71gt0v79N0v)

Comment: Yup, this looks valid now. As far as I can tell, the most likely output is now 0, with probability 1/112, so that's your score.

Comment: You can improve this to 1/230, if you take a full byte from your random function.  [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY/NasMwEITvegqRUiPROk1LAwG1vZQeeugtvcbY@nEWHNlIq1Aa/OyuZMeUkD3tfswMszKvpRwGFIaBRVoxzk@mdSwuD5ss61ykhi3yBReYP63XAl@Tpgso96VjePu4unvecNEPN2BlE5SmL8GCR7Xcv5F/FkED1RWD9hIhHHQiJJVxpVUVIOPkRGgcpzE4O2LGaUZXP8YI0k/iQwmWHVtQs9qjCxJpSvSdlhS9GHmwHmqrFU2uWNUCQtnAr1aCjILZUdQaWYb@nm4/vz6K7@07Pyv8WAH9Eo@F9TF7R6dj2qOvg1Rxd5k/2w07fxZBP/wB "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Comment: @PostRockGarfHunter I can improve it a lot more if I take numbers in a range of [0, -LONG_MIN/4) assuming LONG_MIN/4 % 10 == -2.

Comment: @Post Also, that 8 is intentionally `(15+1)/2`, so the probability of the number being positive or negative is equal.

Answer (score 3):

## Pyth, score of the order \$f_{\varphi(\omega,0)+1}(10^{10^{64}})^{-1}\$

```
M,-.<hG@H1.<hH@G1+@G1@H1D%ZYI<hZ0R,_hZ@Z1J,1 0V.<1Y=J%gZJY)R,hJ+@J1YVC*GCG=T@%TT1)K0WOT=+K1)IO2K.?_K
```

[Don't try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcexCsMgEIDhV8niYDXidVZ6kILJSQkESfGWjLkxQ5Y@vXX4@fiv3y2tfezogiScoTNjAtPr91ZclyDsN3sIIwNZGPzuAtRI6mSqerNCBgnqPj3SlGJBVQro7L9riSaDXtZndq8jt/YH)

## Pyth, score of the order \$f_{\varphi(\omega,0)+\omega}(4)^{-1}\$

(More precisely around \$f_{\varphi(\omega,0)+4}(10)^{-1}\$)

```
M,-.<hG@H1.<hH@G1+@G1@H1D%dYI<hd0R,_hd@d1J,1 0V.<1Y=J%gdJY)R,hJ+@J1YVTVTVTVT=T@%TT1;WOT=+Z1)IO2Z.?_Z
```

[Don't try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/31dHV88mw93BwxBIeTi4G2oDMZDnopoS6WmTkWIQpBOfkeKQYuilY6hgEKZnYxhp66WanuIVqRmkk@Gl7eBlGBkWAoG2IQ6qISGG1uH@IbbaUYaanv5GUXr28VH//wMA)

## Original python, but in the Pyth I made changes to increase size:

```py
import random
g=lambda G,H:(G[0]<<H[1]-H[0]<<G[1],G[1]+H[1])
def C(Z,Y):
  if Z[0]<0: return -Z[0],Z[1]
  J=(1,0)
  for N in range(1<<Y):J=C(g(Z,J))
  return J[0],J[1]+Y
T=10
for N in range(T): T=C(T,T)[1]
K=0
while random.randint(0,T):
  K+=1
if random.randint(0,1):
  print(K)
else:
  print(-K)
```

## Explanation

This uses the extremely fast growing functions \$M_n\$ defined [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2205.11017.pdf). They're actually my go-to when I need fast-growing functions, since they have a growth rate approaching \$\varphi(\omega,0)\$ and are simple to implement. Since they operate on fractions, I use the representation \$(a,b)=\frac{a}{2^b}\$. I iterate the operation \$n\mapsto M_{2^n}(n)\$ starting from 10 roughly \$10^{10^{64}}\$ times, then output integers in a geometric distribution with parameter \$\frac{1}{n}\$, with signs attached. Thus, the score is \$\frac{1}{n}\$. Yes, you can slightly improve it, but it's so big your improvements are negligible.

Yes, this absolutely dominates every other entry so far.

Comment: can we have link to test online :-)

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 26 bytes, score 0.0005

```
Ｗ‽φ⊞υωＩ⎇‽²Ｌυ±⊕Ｌυ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYpBCoNADADvvmKPWbCw9urRk1BEih8Ia3CFNUKMFV8fpdDOaWAmJpS4YjY70pzJwRt5XBeoQgjeu37fEuylO3xd9DKzQoObwkDCKOdvfvrSvYgnvd9bO5pQCVqOQgux0gj/@qU2s8cnXw) Link is to verbose version of code. `0` and `-1` have probabilities of 0.0005, then each subsequent integer has a probability 0.999 times that of the previous. Obviously there are still 75 bytes with which to create some form of arbitrary large expression in order to obtain a lower score, but the resulting code would take longer than the heat death of the universe to run, so it's not quite suitable for TIO. Explanation:

```
Ｗ‽φ
```

While a random number `0..999` is non-zero...

```
⊞υω
```

...push the empty string to the empty list.

```
Ｉ⎇‽²Ｌυ±⊕Ｌυ
```

Randomly print either the length of the list or `-1` minus that length.

Answer (score -1):

## bash + linux, 1 / big number

```
cat /dev/random | hexdump -n `b` -ve '/1 "%02u"'
```

This program will print out 'b' bytes of decimal digits, where b is a program producing a random input number.

(edited to try to be more infinity-ish, although technically still limited by the bash shell)

Comment: The spec explicitly requires `Every integer is a possible output.` A very large number of possible integers != every integer.

Comment: sorry! thats what i get for coding at 3 am.

Comment: looking at this again, other solutions have limited output as well. ??